# azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to deploy an application on Azure but I'm facing some problems.

on my dev box, all works fine but I have a problem when I'm trying to use the application once it is deployed.

on the dev box, I have an action that I do manually wich crates the test tables in my local sql server express.

but I do not know how to create the tables on the server ? so when I run my website application, it says TableNotFound.

Can sy guide me through this final step ? do I need to make sg additional ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table storage client provides a method to create the schema in the cloud storage; I forget the name (will look it up in a second); call that when you initialise whatever you're using as your data service layer.

**Edit:** The following snippet is what I use:

```
StorageAccountInfo = StorageAccountInfo.GetDefaultTableStorageAccountFromConfiguration();
TableStorage.CreateTablesFromModel( typeof( <Context> ), info );
```

where `<Context>` is your data context object.

Comment: perfect, thx you very much.

I guess I've missed that part.

thx you very much